# MapKit error when using AnnotatedItem in a ForEach

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I am using MapKit in SwiftUI and I'm trying to create an array of `AnnotatedItem`s based off an imported JSON.

```
 let countries = Bundle.main.decode("Countries.json")
```

---

```
  private var pointsOfInterest = [
        ForEach(countries) { country in 
            AnnotatedItem(name: country.display_name, coordinate: .init(latitude: country.latitude, longitude: country.longitude))
        }
    ]
```

Without a `ForEach` using a static values, it works...but when I added the `ForEach`, I get the following errors:

> Referencing initializer 'init(_:content:)' on 'ForEach' requires that 'AnnotatedItem' conform to 'View'
> Static method 'buildBlock' requires that 'AnnotatedItem' conform to 'View'

I am fairly new to Swift so I don't know how to quite interpret the error.  How would I conform `AnnotatedItem` to View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ForEach` is for use inside a `View` hierarchy. You may be thinking of `forEach`, which can be used to perform loops on array elements, but it appears that what you actually want in this case is `.map`, which allows you to transform one array into another:

```
private var pointsOfInterest : [AnnotatedItem] {
  countries.map { country in 
    AnnotatedItem(name: country.display_name, coordinate: .init(latitude: country.latitude, longitude: country.longitude))
  }
}
```